# R: Wanting to aggregate (sum totals, and count of complete cases) by value within a column

Tags: r, sum

I have a data.frame called **dataSet** and within that data.frame I would like to be able to reference a value in a particular column (as it's a repeated value) and aggregate/sum the totals by each value.

I know I can call a particular column. For instance to call the 4th column data I would use this.

```
dataSet[,4]
```

if dataSet looked like this:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
 3    6    2    1
 5    2    6    2
 5    6    12   3
 4    3    NA   4
 5    2    NA   3
 7    6    NA   1
 6    6    19   4
 9    3    2    1
```

I'd want to be able to aggregate (group by, for those of you who know SQL) the col4 values.

One, the sum (of any column I choose), say Col4 in this case. But ideally I could put the column as a variable and call a value from any column.

So I would have answers for that **sum** col1 for each common value of col4, like this:

```
col1 col4
19     1
 5     2
10     3   
10     4
```

Two, the number of complete cases, as signified by the "count" column.

```
count col4
2    1
1    2
1    3  
1    4
```

Being new to R, I find the struggle in how to reference (or call) for particular values in columns. I have the reference part down for a dataframe[i,j] where i = row, j = col. I guess a tertiary question would be, where can I learn more about how to make references(or calls) on columns and values to on all objects within R (e.g. lists, data.frames)

Answer (score 1):

You can used the `aggregate` function to find the sum of values in column1 for each unique value in column4. ( documentation for this function can be found by entering `help(aggregate)` at the R command prompt) The syntax would look like this:

```
aggregate(x=dataSet$col1, by=list(dataSet$col4), FUN=sum)
```

or, giving the same result:

```
aggregate(x=dataSet[,"col1"], by=list(dataSet[,"col4"]), FUN=sum)
```

Needing to give a `list` for `by` argument to `aggregate` seemed a little odd to me at first, but it allows you to provide multiple fields to group your values (passed with the argument `x`) by and is thus equivalent to the `group by` clause in SQL.

To find the count of occurrences of a certain value in a column you can use the `table` function:

```
table(dataSet$col4)
```

or, giving the same result:

```
table(dataSet[,"col4"])
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
d <- structure(list(col1 = c(3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 6L, 9L), col2 = c(6L, 
2L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 6L, 6L, 3L), col3 = c(2L, 6L, 12L, NA, NA, NA, 
19L, 2L), col4 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L)), .Names = c("col1", 
"col2", "col3", "col4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

library(reshape)
d1 <- melt.data.frame(d, id = 'col4')
d1$variable <- as.character(d1$variable)
head(d1)
      col4 variable value
1    1     col1     3
2    2     col1     5
3    3     col1     5
4    4     col1     4
5    3     col1     5
6    1     col1     7
library(dplyr)
d1 %.%
  group_by(variable, col4) %.%
  summarise(
    s = sum(value, na.rm = T),
    c = length(na.omit(value)))
Source: local data frame [12 x 4]
Groups: variable

   variable col4  s c
1      col1    1 19 3
2      col1    2  5 1
3      col1    3 10 2
4      col1    4 10 2
5      col2    1 15 3
6      col2    2  2 1
7      col2    3  8 2
8      col2    4  9 2
9      col3    1  4 2
10     col3    2  6 1
11     col3    3 12 1
12     col3    4 19 1
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure the direction this is going. The answer below hits in the direction I was looking. One for summing one column (Col1) based on col4. 

The 2nd part would be to count complete.cases.

Comment: This is what you get with these approaches. Just try it. Your count may not be correct. Try it with the table solution proposed by @samhiggins2001 and with my code.

Comment: It's probably a little over my head (appreciate it though - stretches me). I can't get the 'd' in the d1 function. I'm assuming that's my directory or data.frame correct? 

I get this error:

Comment: > d1 <- melt.data.frame(onedataset, id = "ID")

Comment: Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated

Comment: something is going wrong with your data.frame d and the way you are reading it. try `d <- read.table(text=readClipboard(), header=TRUE)` on your data above.

Comment: I still can't get it to work...user error on my end (likely). I tried reposting here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23634572/r-sum-complete-cases-in-one-column-grouped-by-or-sorted-by-a-value-in-another