# R: Sum Complete.cases in one column grouped by (or sorted by) a value in another column

Tags: r, sorting, aggregate

I'm using the `airquality` data set available in R, and attempting to count the number of rows within the data that do not contain any `NA`s, while aggregating by `Month`.

The data looks like this:

```
head(airquality)
#   Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
# 1    41     190  7.4   67     5   1
# 2    36     118  8.0   72     5   2
# 3    12     149 12.6   74     5   3
# 4    18     313 11.5   62     5   4
# 5    NA      NA 14.3   56     5   5
# 6    28      NA 14.9   66     5   6
```

As you can see, I have `NA`s in columns `Ozone` and `Solar.R`. I used the function `complete.cases` as follows:

```
x  <- airquality[,1] # for the Ozone
y  <- airquality[,2] # for the Solar.R
ok <- complete.cases(x,y)
```

And then to check:

```
nrow(airquality)
# [1] 153
sum(!ok)
# [1] 42
sum(ok)
# [1] 111
```

which is great.

But now, I'd like to pull that data apart to sort by `Month` (Column5) and this is where I'm running into problems - in trying to `aggregate` or `sort` by the value in column5 (`Month`).

I was able to get this to run, it won't sort by `Month` yet (I just wanted to make sure I could get the function to run):

```
aggregate(x = sum(complete.cases(airquality)), by= list(nrow(airquality)), FUN = sum)
#   Group.1   x
# 1     153 111
```

OK... so to sort it out. I am trying to use the `by` part of the aggregate function to sort. I tried many variations of the column5 within `airquality`.

```
- airquality[,5]
- airquality[,"Month"]
```

I get these errors:

```
aggregate(x = sum(complete.cases(airquality)), by= list(airquality[,5]), FUN = sum)
# Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
#   arguments must have same length

aggregate(x = sum(complete.cases(airquality)), by= 
      list(sum(complete.cases(airquality)),airquality[,5]), FUN = sum)
# Error in aggregate.data.frame(as.data.frame(x), ...) : 
#   arguments must have same length
```

I tried to search further into the `?aggregate(x, ...)` function. Namely on the `by` part...

> by - a list of grouping elements, each as long as the variables in the data frame x. The elements are coerced to factors before use.

I looked up `?factor`, but can't seem to see how to apply it (if even necessary in this case). I also tried putting `break =` into it but didn't work.

None of the *"Questions that may already have your answer"* seem to apply, many of which give solutions in C# and SQL.

Edit: Expected outcome

```
Count  Month
  24       5
   9       6
  26       7
  23       8
  29       9
```

Comment: Could you add what your desired output is? From your initial paragraph ("count rows within air quality that do not contain complete.cases by Month"), it looks like `table(airquality[!ok,"Month"])` might do what you want. If not, please clarify.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, thanks Stephan. I added the expected outcome at the bottom of the post. So yes, your statement looks correct in the type of output I want (assuming R could do it that way). thanks

Comment: Being new to R...I had not been exposed to either answer method below (data.tables vs using package "dplyr")...and so I'm trying to 1) learn them and 2) learn when to best use them. I'm adding this as an addendum to maybe help that as @StephanKolassa, Simon O'Hanlon, and beginneR all gave me answers that worked. 

http://www.r-bloggers.com/when-i-use-plyrdplyr/

Answer (score 6):

As an addition to the other answers, you could do it with `dplyr`.

```
require(dplyr)

airquality %.%
  group_by(Month) %.%
  summarize(incomplete = sum(!complete.cases(Ozone, Solar.R)),
             complete = sum(complete.cases(Ozone, Solar.R)))

#  Month incomplete complete
#1     5          7       24
#2     6         21        9
#3     7          5       26
#4     8          8       23
#5     9          1       29
```

Comment: The other answer worked for me, but I want to try this. I'm new to R (less than 2 weeks in)...but looking to get into get into heavier statistical analysis, so I appreciate being stretched here. 

This is great...worked very well. Question, can I put as many "aggregating" like functions/calls in the summarize box as I want? Say I wanted to add the mean, the mode, etc.

Comment: @PaulDeVos yes, you can put as many as you want. You can have a look at the introduction to `dplyr` here: http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html. For example, you could add: `, mean(Wind)` before the last `)` and check the result.

Answer (score 4):

I like `data.table` for these kinds of problems. It does `by` grouping very well and intuitively indeed...

```
require( data.table )
dt <- data.table( airquality )
dt[ , list( Count = sum( complete.cases( Ozone , Solar.R ) ) ), by = Month ]

#   Month Count
#1:     5 24
#2:     6  9
#3:     7 26
#4:     8 23
#5:     9 29
```

Keeping it in `base` R I'd do...

```
airquality$ok <- complete.cases( airquality$Ozone , airquality$Solar.R )
aggregate( ok ~ Month , data = airquality , FUN = sum )
#  Month ok
#1     5 24
#2     6  9
#3     7 26
#4     8 23
#5     9 29
```

---

**Edit:** Another variation of @Simon's solution using `data.table`:

```
dt[complete.cases(Ozone, Solar.R), list(count = .N), by=Month]
#    Month count
# 1:     5    24
# 2:     6     9
# 3:     7    26
# 4:     8    23
# 5:     9    29
```

The variation is that we first filter/subset only those with *no `NA`s* and then get the aggregation by `Month`.

> Note: `.N` is an inbuilt variable in `data.table` - an integer vector of length 1, which gives the total number of observations in that group.

Comment: Nice job on the `base` R addition using `aggregate`

Comment: By the way, what is `complete`?  Is that a variable?  Doesn't seem to be a function.

Comment: @user1477388 where is that? I have `complete.cases` - i don't see that I have used `complete` anywhere?

Comment: I assumed `complete` was an object with a property or method of `cases`.  I was referring to `complete.cases`.

Comment: @user1477388 ah. R doesn't work quite the same way as say java. Method dispatch for generic methods usually occurs based on the class of an object. `complete.cases` is a function.

Comment: I installed and used the library() to use data.table...is there a case when to use require() over library()? I apologize, I'm 1.5 weeks into learning R. And it's not quite as intuitive to me as say Python, at least not yet. 

Also, what could I do to isolate only months = 6,7 ?

Comment: no not at all. The difference is that if you have a script and use `require` if R cannot load your library (e.g. you haven't installed it), your script will not stop, it will just not load the package (`require` returns the value `FALSE` I believe). This is not the case with library. I guess I just prefer `require` but use either at your convenience really.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

```
> foo <- table(airquality[!ok,"Month"])
> data.frame(Month=names(foo),Count=as.vector(foo))
  Month Count
1     5     7
2     6    21
3     7     5
4     8     8
5     9     1
```

(This looks a little different from your edit. Is it possible that there is some small confusion between `ok` and `!ok`?)

Comment: Just change `!ok` to `ok`.